# Multiple image page with favourite option - how to use localStorage to remember which images have been favourited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

So I have a page with images on it that have a star icon so the user can favourite. Each image has this. I want the user to be able to click and it will favourite these through changing the image class. Using localStorage means they can return on future sessions with there favourited ones still favourited. So far I have:

```
if (window.localStorage) {
 var didTheyFave = $('.icon-star-empty').each(function() {
(this).click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('icon-star')) {
     $( this ).addClass( 'icon-star-empty' ); 
     $( this ).removeClass( 'icon-star' );
     var fav = false;
} else {
     $( this ).addClass( 'icon-star' ); 
     $( this ).removeClass( 'icon-star-empty' );
     var fav = true;
}
 localStorage.setItem('didTheyFave', fav);
 })
});
}
```

And then to getItem:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var favResult = localStorage.getItem('didTheyFave');
if ( favResult = true ) {
    $('.icon-star-empty').addClass( 'icon-star' ); 
}
}); // I know this last bit is incorrect but testing things to see if they work!
```

Comment: Are you storing any form of index to check which is true and which is false?

Comment: No, I'm not at the moment.

Comment: You surely need to save the `favResult` for each of the image separately otherwise you cant retrieve them if they are always being written into the same variable in localStorage.

Comment: OK, so I tried something like this (above)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use AJAX with your chosen server language (php etc.) -> write a cookie to browser -> change item class/css...?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function() {
function assignFavStar(){
   $('.commonClassUsedforEachStar').each(function(index){
         //get localStorage item for each
          if ( favResult === true ) {//do this first
               $('.commonClassUsedforEachStar').addClass( 'icon-star' ); 
          } else {
                 $('.commonClassUsedforEachStar').addClass( 'icon-star-empty' ); 
           }

   });

}
}
```

Try if you can do something like this, not bulletproof but can start you off on this.

```
if (window.localStorage) {
  var didTheyFave = $('.icon-star-empty').click(function() {
   if($(this).hasClass('icon-star')) {
     $( this ).addClass( 'icon-star-empty' ); 
     $( this ).removeClass( 'icon-star' );
     var fav = false;
 } else {
     $( this ).addClass( 'icon-star' ); 
     $( this ).removeClass( 'icon-star-empty' );
     var fav = true;
 }
 localStorage.setItem('didTheyFave', fav);
});
}
```

`localStorage.setItem('didTheyFave', fav);`
this line is always setting to true/ false and overwritting the previous value. You need to check which is set as true and which is set as false.

You can try using the index while setting it, for example, when the user clicks on a star get the location of that, take that location and add it to `didTheyFave`, so now your key which you are saving in the localStorage would look like `didTheyFave1` or `didTheyFave2` and so on, and you can loop over these and set the true/false values while retrieving.

Comment: Thanks, I tried implementing what you suggested but no change. Yeh, I'm trying to work out the best way of checking whats set to true and what's set to false. Any suggestions?